# Pandas: replace values in columns using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have 2 dataframe and I need to get new column to first dataframe, using values from second
FIrse df is

```
ID,"url","used_at","active_seconds"
8075643aab791cec7dc9d18926958b67,"sberbank.ru/ru/person/promo/10mnl?utm_source=Vesti.ru&utm_medium=html&utm_campaign=10_million_users_SBOL_dec2015&utm_term=every14_syncbanners",2016-01-01 00:03:16,183
a04a8041ffa6fe1b85471ca5af1ee575,"online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/rslogin.jsp?credit=false",2016-01-01 00:04:36,42
a04a8041ffa6fe1b85471ca5af1ee575,"online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/sms/sms.jsp?smsAuth=true",2016-01-01 00:05:18,22
a04a8041ffa6fe1b85471ca5af1ee575,"online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/RSIndex.jspx",2016-01-01 00:05:40,14
a04a8041ffa6fe1b85471ca5af1ee575,"online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/payments/PaymentReq.jspx",2016-01-01 00:05:54,22
ba880911a6d54f6ea6d3145081a0e0dd,"homecredit.ru/help/quest/feedback.php",2016-01-01 00:06:12,2
```

Second df looks like

```
URL Code
citibank\.ru\/russia\/info\/rus\/contacts_form\.htm 15
citibank\.ru\/russia\/info\/rus\/contacts\.htm  15
gazprombank\.ru\/contacts\/ 15
gazprombank\.ru\/feedback\/ 15
gazprombank\.ru\/additional_office\/    15
homecredit\.ru\/help\/quest\/feedback\.php  15
homecredit\.ru\/offices\/*  15
```

If I don't have a regex, I use

```
df1['code'] = df1.url.map(df2.set_index('URL')['Code'])
```

But I can't do this, because `df2.URL` is regex.
But

```
df1['code'] = df1['url'].replace(df2['URL'], df2['Code'], regex=True)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Looking at `pandas.Series.replace()` I'm not sure if the method is supposed to work properly when series objects are passed to it as the `to_replace` and `value` arguments. Have you tried using `Series.values`, as in `df1['code'] = df1['url'].replace(df2['URL'].values, df2['Code'].values, regex=True)`?

Comment: @IanS it returns `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: @cant I get `sre_constants.error: bad character range`

Comment: @cant it returns `df1.url` in `df1.code`, not `df2.Code`

Comment: @PetrPetrov the way your code is done, it can only return `df2.Code` in rows where the contents of `df1.url` entirely match the regex string (as can be seen i my answer below). Otherwise it would return either `df1.url` or part of `df1.url` with `df2.Code` somewhere in the string in case of a partial match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the `pandas.Series.replace()` method doesn't allow `Series` objects as the `to_replace` and `value` arguments. Passing lists instead works:

```
df1['code'] = df1.url.replace(df2.URL.values, df2.Code.values, regex=True)
print df1[['url', 'code']]
```

produces the following output:

```
                                                 url  \
0  sberbank.ru/ru/person/promo/10mnl?utm_source=V...   
1  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/rslogin.js...   
2  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/sms/sms.js...   
3             online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/RSIndex.jspx   
4  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/payments/PaymentReq....   
5              homecredit.ru/help/quest/feedback.php   

                                                code  
0  sberbank.ru/ru/person/promo/10mnl?utm_source=V...  
1  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/rslogin.js...  
2  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/sms/sms.js...  
3             online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/RSIndex.jspx  
4  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/payments/PaymentReq....  
5                                                 15
```

In answer to your additional comments, you can't get `df2.Code` in `df1.code` in rows where `df1.url` doesn't match any of the regex strings, but you can provide a value (e.g. `None`) for these cases to be put in the column instead. This is, for example, done by adding the following line:

```
df1['code'] = df1.apply(lambda x: None if x.code == x.url else x.code, axis=1)
```

where `print df1[['url', 'code']]` returns the following:

```
                                                 url  code
0  sberbank.ru/ru/person/promo/10mnl?utm_source=V...   NaN
1  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/rslogin.js...   NaN
2  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/system/login/sms/sms.js...   NaN
3             online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/RSIndex.jspx   NaN
4  online.rsb.ru/hb/faces/rs/payments/PaymentReq....   NaN
5              homecredit.ru/help/quest/feedback.php  15.0
```

Comment: How can I get only code to `df1['code]`? I need get number, that `df1.url` is equal to `df2.URL`?

Comment: But if `df1['url']` is a `alfabank.ru/get-money/credit/credit-cash/#frame_credit_calc/buy` and `df2['URL']` is a `alfabank.ru/get-money/credit/credit-cash/#frame_credit_calc` and code from `df2['Code']` is 3. When I replace I get `3/buy` and after I get to `df1['code'] = '3/buy'. How can I get 3 to it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, adding `.*` to the end of that string would match any url that begins with it.